# Android layout state condition

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a check box in my view and an EditText.
I would like to enable my editText only when CheckBox is checked directly with layout condition :

```
 android:enabled="@{checkBox.isChecked}"
```

but i have a compilation error. How can i do this ?

Thank's

Comment: cant do it from layout..do it programatically

Answer (score 1):

You should set your `edittext` to enabled false. And in your `checkBox` listener do something like this:

```
checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) 
    {
         if(compoundButton.isChecked){
                editText.setFocusable(true);
                editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                editText.setCursorVisible(true);
                editText.setEnabled(true);
    }else{
                editText.setFocusable(false);
                editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
                editText.setCursorVisible(false);
                editText.setEnabled(false);
}

   }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The xml loads at compile time, in life cycle onCreate() method calls.
After that only user has vsisbility to the layout.
You are providing a null to the condition beacuse the checkbox is not even initialised while you  try to find its state.
Write the code to find the checkbox state and assign it to the editext or textbox in the onResume method.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

check this for better understanding...